# I dont understanding eloquent js "a list" exercise (I have some odd result)

Tags: javascript

I'm at the moment doing the exercises in the EloquentJS book. 
chapter 4, "a list" exercise, more precisely. The exercise consist of creating and deconstructing a list from and to an array.

I've tried something that look pretty logic to me but I get a return that i don't understand.
I get a Circular tag/marker.

Here's my first try and my second try separately:

```
function arrayToListTry1 (array) {
  /**My solution try 1
  My observations:
  I was building it inverted (last elem in first place
  I don't understand why my version gets a circular result and the book solution doesn't
  */
    let list = {
        value: "",
        rest: {}
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        list.rest = list;
        list.value = array[i];
    }

    return list;
}
/**result: 
node eloquentJS_chapter4_ex_arrayToList.js
{ rest: [Circular], value: 'hello' }
*/

function arrayToListTry2 (array) {

    let list = {};

    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list.rest = list;
        list.value = array[i];
    }
    return list;
}

//same result
```

The exercise solution shows an other way I've checked it but don't understand clearly whats the problem with my solution.
I've also checked on stackoverflow what others are saying about this exercise but don't find an explanation i understand.

Here is the actual exercise solution:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  }
  return list;
}

/**
result:
node eloquentJS_chapter4_ex_arrayToList.js
{ value: 'hello',
  rest: { value: 'world', rest: { value: '!!!', rest: null } } }
*/
```

---

Edit:
Here's my final result, I will just past the whole file content. Thanks every one.

```
let listValue = {
    value: "hello",
    rest: {
        value: "world",
        rest: {
            value: "!!!",
            rest: {}
        }
    }
};

const arrayValue = ["hello", "world", "!!!"];

function arrayToList (array){
    /**Actual solution from book:
    */
// let list = null;
// for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
//   list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
// }
// return list;

  /**My solution try 1
  My observations:
  I was building it inverted (last elem in first place
  I dont understand why my version gets a circular result and the book solution doesnt
  */
//  let list = {
// //       value: "",
// //       rest: {
// //
// //       }
//  };
//
//  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
//      list.rest = list;
//      list.value = array[i];
//      // console.log(list);
//      // console.log(list.rest);
//  }
//  //console.log(list.rest);
//  // console.log("result:");
//  return list;

  /** try 2
  */
// let list = {};
//
// for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
//  list.rest = list;
//  list.value = array[i];
// }
// return list;

/** try 3
    Every loop creates a new list object containing the old one.
    But i still dont see why my tries above don't work.
*/
    let list = {};

    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list = {
            value: array[i],
            rest: list
        }
        // console.log(list);
    }

    return list;
}
/***
An other possibility that relate more to my thought process. Given to me on stackoverflow
function arrayToListTry4 (array) {
    let list = {}
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list.rest = Object.assign({}, list);
        list.value = array[i];
    }

    return list
}
**/


function listToArray (list){
    let arr = [];

    while (list.rest !== undefined ) {
        arr.push(list.value);
        list = list.rest;
        // console.log(list);
        // console.log(arr);
    }

    return arr;
}


function prepend (item, list){

    return { value: item, rest: list};
}


function nth (list, nth){
    for (var i = 0; i < nth -1; i++) {
        list = list.rest
    }

    return list.value
}


function recNth (list, nth){

    if (nth - 1 == 0) {
        return list.value;
    } else {
        return recGetNth(list.rest, nth -1);
    }
}


console.log(arrayToList(arrayValue));
// → { value: 'hello',
       rest: { value: 'world', rest: { value: '!!!', rest: {} } } }

console.log(listToArray(list));
// → [ 'hello', 'world', '!!!' ]

console.log(listToArray(arrayToList(arrayValue)));
// → [ 'hello', 'world', '!!!' ]

console.log(arrayToList(listToArray(listValue)));
// → { value: 'hello',
       rest: { value: 'world', rest: { value: '!!!', rest: {} } } }

console.log(prepend("Hey", listValue));
// → { value: 'Hey',
       rest: { value: 'hello', rest: { value: 'world', rest: { value: '!!!', rest: {} } } } }

console.log(nth(listValue, 3));
// → "!!!"

console.log(recNth(listValue, 2));
// → "world"
```

Comment: "*a list exercise, more precisely*" and what exactly is the goal of the exercise?

Comment: I've also tried to JSON.stringify my list but it return the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `list.rest = list;` you are setting the list.rest property back as a reference to itself which is why it says "Circular". This is because in Javascript, [Objects and Arrays are passed by reference](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c).

What you want to do is create a deep-copy of the original element. You can do that a few ways:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list))` will deconstruct to and from JSON (preserving all keys and all object depth). Alternatively `Object.assign({}, list)` will assign all of the object's 1st level keys to the new object. This means an object like this:

```
{
   root: {
      inner: "test",
   }
}
```

Will only be assigned the `root` key, but the `inner` will not get copied when doing `Object.assign`

Thus a solution for you would be:

```js
for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list.rest = Object.assign({}, list);
        list.value = array[i];
    }
```

or

```js
for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list.rest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list));
        list.value = array[i];
    }
```

Comment: Thank a lot that exactly what I was asking for. It seems like  I had some misunderstanding on this concept about JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is basically this statement:

```
list.rest = list; // this gets constantly reassigned
list.value = array[array.length - 1];
```

As `rest` is the same as `list`, there as a cycle and JS shows you this cycle.

The book solution avoids this problem by creating new lists instead of reusing the same list again and again.